# inline Shell script code in Visual c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shell, visual-c++

I was wondering if it is possible to write inline (embedded) shell script code within a Visual c++ code..

or maybe call a shell script file from visual C++ code..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a shell script but I suspect you could accomplish what you need with T4, all without leaving Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx